# 2 year old user is a new contributor?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-users, meta

Just saw this:

[image: Yufenyuy rep]

a 1400 rep new user? **Wow! He's learning fast** until I clicked [his profile](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/531149/yufenyuy-veyeh-dider) and he's a 2 YO user?

[image: Yufenyuy Profile]

#### Bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is by design. First, the meta site and the main site are considered separately in this regard: the activity on one does not affect New Contributor status on the other. ([Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314509/update-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-meta-to-say-new-contributor-to-meta)). You are seeing the icon on meta.

Second, the criterion is the age of the oldest  non-deleted post on the site, not the age of account. From the [spec](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314476):

> To set the bit, we look for a user's oldest non-deleted question or answer. If one doesn't exist or that found post is less than a week old, we mark the post as OwnerIsNewPoster.